# In Gradle, how to set unique system property before each execution of JUnit test class?

Tags: gradle, junit

In the gradle script below, `maxParallelForks` and `forkEvery` will start a new process with a new JVM per Junit test class. **Is there a way to give each test process/JVM/Junit class its own unique system property?**

I tried an experiment where I passed a UUID value as a system property in the `beforeSuite` method.

```
apply plugin:'java'
test {
    ignoreFailures = true
    maxParallelForks = 8
    forkEvery = 1
    systemProperty 'some.prop', 'value'

   beforeSuite { descriptor ->
    logger.lifecycle("Before suite: " + descriptor)
    def theuuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    println "beforeSuite uuid =" + theuuid
    systemProperty 'some.uuid', theuuid
   }
   beforeTest { descriptor ->
      logger.lifecycle("Running test: " + descriptor)
   }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The JUnit test classes, `LoginTest1` and `LoginTest2` print out the system property in a test method.

```
public class LoginTest1 {
    private String userName="Gradle";
@Test
    public void testUserName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("LoginTest1: Testing Login ");

        System.out.println("LoginTest1: Testing Login some.prop -> " 
           + System.getProperty("some.prop"));
        System.out.println("LoginTest1: Testing Login some.uuid -> " 
           + System.getProperty("some.uuid"));

    assertTrue(userName.equals("Gradle"));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class LoginTest2 {
    private String userName="Gradle";

@Test
    public void testUserName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("LoginTest2: Testing Login ");

        System.out.println("LoginTest2: Testing Login some.prop -> " 
           + System.getProperty("some.prop"));
        System.out.println("LoginTest2: Testing Login some.uuid -> " 
           + System.getProperty("some.uuid"));

    assertTrue(userName.equals("Gradle"));
        }
}
```

---

As you can see from the gradle output below, the `beforeSuite` method is called before running individual JUnit test methods.  Both test classes get the same system property of `6a006689-474f-47d5-9649-a88c92b45095`

```
 $ gradle clean test

> Task :test 
Before suite: Gradle Test Run :test
beforeSuite uuid =6a006689-474f-47d5-9649-a88c92b45095
Before suite: Gradle Test Executor 1
beforeSuite uuid =39edb608-3027-4ad8-bd15-f52f50175582
Before suite: Test class ch6.login.LoginTest1
beforeSuite uuid =c0ce55e0-924c-4319-becb-bc27229c9cf3
Before suite: Gradle Test Executor 2
beforeSuite uuid =c15eaac0-7ea7-46d2-8235-8dc49b3f7a39
Running test: Test testUserNameNotNull(ch6.login.LoginTest1)
Before suite: Test class ch6.login.LoginTest2
beforeSuite uuid =73abbe24-5b78-4935-867a-445ac4ac20ef
Running test: Test testUserName(ch6.login.LoginTest1)
Running test: Test testUserName(ch6.login.LoginTest2)
```

---

JUnit test class output:

```
LoginTest1: Testing Login 
LoginTest1: Testing Login some.prop -> value
LoginTest1: Testing Login some.uuid -> 6a006689-474f-47d5-9649-a88c92b45095

LoginTest2: Testing Login 
LoginTest2: Testing Login some.prop -> value
LoginTest2: Testing Login some.uuid -> 6a006689-474f-47d5-9649-a88c92b45095
```

It looks like there's an initial call to beforeSuite (seen as ":test") and then once per Test Executor. The first uuid value ("6a006689") is set across all JVMs. **Is there anything like a simple beforeClass method I could use?**

---

In the debug log below,it looks like the Test Executors are given the jvm argument `-Dsome.uuid=6a006689-474f-47d5-9649-a88c92b45095` and that is used soley to create new JVMs (as per the `forkEvery` config). This makes me think that what I want to do is impossible in Gradle.

```
20:23:42.466 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'. Working directory: /a/b/ Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dorg.g
radle.native=false -Dsome.prop=value -Dsome.uuid=6a006689-474f-47d5-9649-a88c92b45095 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -cp /data/.gradle/caches/4.3.1/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 1'

20:23:42.466 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 2'. Working directory: /a/b/ Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dorg.g
radle.native=false -Dsome.prop=value -Dsome.uuid=6a006689-474f-47d5-9649-a88c92b45095 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -cp /data/.gradle/caches/4.3.1/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 2'
```

### Update 8/2018

### The following solution does not work in Gradle 4.9 and greater

Instead, there is a org.gradle.test.worker system property which you can use to distinguish between workers, calculate display names, temporary directories, etc. This test.worker is simply an increasing long value. The Gradle team has no plans on making Test Workers configurable. A pity because I had to do some major refactoring in my test code in order to upgrade Gradle. The "@BeforeAllCallback" in JUnit 5 might be useful to you.

### Trying to solve by intercepting Test.copyTo(JavaForkOptions target)

***This code demonstrates lance-java 's suggestion and succeeds in answering my question.*** I have the following build.gradle script which uses MyTestTask to extend Test and add a unique value called `my_uuid`. Note that the build script must have forkEvery = 1 to ensure `copyTo` is called once per JUnit test:

```
class MyTestTask extends Test {

 public Test copyTo(JavaForkOptions target) {
        super.copyTo(target);
      String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println("MyTestTask copyTo:\n my_uuid=" +  uuid);
        System.out.println("\t before getJvmArgs:" +  target.getJvmArgs());
        System.out.println("\t before getSystemProperties:" +  target.getSystemProperties());

        target.systemProperty("my_uuid", uuid);

        System.out.println("\t after getJvmArgs:" +  target.getJvmArgs());
        System.out.println("\t after getSystemProperties:" +  target.getSystemProperties());

        return this;
    }

}
///

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }


    test {
        enabled false // This doesn't seem to matter.

    }

    task my_test(type: MyTestTask) {

        forkEvery 1 // need this so copyTo called each JUnit test

        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

        doFirst {
            def uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            println "TEST:Task name is $name. In doFirst. uuid is " + uuid

            jvmArgs '-Dcommon_uuid='+ uuid

        }
    }
}
```

The Junit tests that are executed are trivial and simply print out System.getProperty("my_uuid") and System.getProperty("common_uuid").

```
> Task :CustomCopyToSubProject:my_test 
TEST:Task name is my_test. In doFirst. uuid is eed1ee92-7805-4b8e-a74c-96218d1be6e1
MyTestTask copyTo:
MyTestTask copyTo:
 my_uuid=a7996c20-1085-4397-9e32-fd84467dcb45
 my_uuid=69f6f347-71d0-4e5d-9fad-66bf4468fab3
         before getJvmArgs:[]
         before getJvmArgs:[]
         before getSystemProperties:[common_uuid:eed1ee92-7805-4b8e-a74c-96218d1be6e1]
         before getSystemProperties:[common_uuid:eed1ee92-7805-4b8e-a74c-96218d1be6e1]
         after getJvmArgs:[]
         after getJvmArgs:[]
         after getSystemProperties:[common_uuid:eed1ee92-7805-4b8e-a74c-96218d1be6e1, my_uuid:69f6f347-71d0-4e5d-9fad-66bf4468fab3]
         after getSystemProperties:[common_uuid:eed1ee92-7805-4b8e-a74c-96218d1be6e1, my_uuid:a7996c20-1085-4397-9e32-fd84467dcb45]

ch3.LoginTest2 > testUserName2 STANDARD_OUT
    LoginTest2.java: Testing Login !  >>---> my_uuid=a7996c20-1085-4397-9e32-fd84467dcb45 common_uuid=eed1ee92-7805-4b8e-a74c-96218d1be6e1

ch3.LoginTest1 > testUserName1 STANDARD_OUT
    LoginTest1.java: Testing Login !  >>---> my_uuid=69f6f347-71d0-4e5d-9fad-66bf4468fab3 common_uuid=eed1ee92-7805-4b8e-a74c-96218d1be6e1
```

The `task my_test` sets `common_uuid` in `doFirst`. The `MyTestTask.copyTo` method sets its own `my_uuid`.
You can see from the output and MyTestTask is called twice, once per JUnit test task (LoginTest1 and LoginTest2). The two JUnit tests get their own unique system property in `my_uuid`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that UUID? If a new JVM is forked for every test you could just use a static field that is initialized with a UUID.

Comment: I’d like every JUnit test class to get a unique UUID. I don’t want multiple classes with the same UUID. Should I make my question more clear?

Comment: @patronizing_bofh The solution doesn't seems to work on gradle 4.9 . `copyTo` method being called only once. What version were you using?

Comment: @L4zy  No, this does not work with gradle 4.9 unfortunately.  There is a   **org.gradle.test.worker** system property which you can use to distinguish between workers, calculate display names, temporary directories, etc. This test.worker is simply an increasing _long_ value.  The Gradle team has no plans on making Test Workers configurable. A pity because I had to do some major refactoring in my test code in order to upgrade Gradle. The "@BeforeAllCallback" in JUnit 5 might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to intercept `Test.copyTo(JavaForkOptions target)`, unfortunately the only way I can see to do this is to extend [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html)

eg

```
public class Test2 extends org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test {
    public Test copyTo(JavaForkOptions target) {
        super.copyTo(target);
        target.systemProperty("uuid", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return this;
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
test {
    enabled = false
}
task test2(type: Test2) {
    // guessing you'll need to configure a bit of stuff here
}
check.dependsOn test2
```

Comment: Hello @lance-java , I tried your suggestion and it did not work. It looks like the `copyTo` is called for each jvm, though, which is good. I can't pass the unique system property into the respective jvm. I documented what I did in the original post under header "Trying to solve by intercepting Test.copyTo(JavaForkOptions target)"

Comment: I don't think you've configured the sources for the new test task so maybe it's not running any tests? Also I can't see you disabling the default test task so perhaps the output is coming from the default task? You are calling `super.copyTo(target);` last. I suggested to call this first. It's possible that this is overriding any system properties you've set. Not sure but worth a try.

Comment: The default sources work fine, you can see the JUnit tests called in the output I posted. Disabling the default test task has no effect. The `super.copyTo(target)` was the problem! I updated my "Trying to ..." section with working code based on your (correct) suggestion! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since a new JVM is forked for every test you could just use a static field that is initialized with a UUID.

```
public class Helper {
    public static final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

public class LoginTest2 {
    private String userName="Gradle";

    @Test
    public void testUserName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("LoginTest2: Testing Login ");

        System.out.println("LoginTest2: Testing Login some.uuid -> " 
           + Helper.uuid;

        assertTrue(userName.equals("Gradle"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this using only Java, but would it be possible to do it all in Gradle?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Is it because there is one shared `JavaForkOptions` as mentioned in this question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780841/setting-system-properties-for-gradle-tests)  ?  I am seeing something in my debug log output.