# How to reserve ports for tests in a Gradle build?

Tags: maven, gradle

I am considering migrating my maven build to gradle, but I could'nt find how to reserve ports for my tests.

In the maven build I use `build-helper-maven-plugin` / `reserve-network-port`, which reserves a port and stores it in a variable so that I can access it from my code and always have an available port.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Are you using a CI solution like Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use it locally and on Jenkins

Comment: On Jenkins there does a exist a plugin to reserve ports which is better than build-helper-maven-plugin for such cases. Locally you don't need it...

Comment: Locally it's needed just as well as on Jenkins, for the same reason. You never run multiple tests at once?

Answer (score 1):

See a related issue [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5304)

It's been suggested that you can use the `org.gradle.test.worker` system property to have a unique worker number for the currently running test. This value could be added to an arbitrary base port number (eg 9000) to guarantee a unique port for each test worker.

Further reading [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-assign-environment-variable-such-that-no-test-running-at-the-same-time-has-the-same-value/25732) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732829/in-gradle-how-to-set-unique-system-property-before-each-execution-of-junit-test)

Comment: It could do the trick, but if I push further, for instance having 2 builds running at the same time (say for 2 different branches), would it work ? (ie: is the worker number sequential or kind of random ?)

Comment: I'm assuming that there's a worker pool with each fork having a unique number (likely incremental from 0 or 1). I think it's safe to assume that the Gradle worker pool is maintained by the Gradle daemon. All of the builds on a single machine should be run by a single Gradle daemon so the worker number should be unique regardless of how many builds are running in parallel. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html. Note: I haven't tested this theory